# QGIS 2.0 Plugins missing

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

At the risk of a series of down votes but I have just installed QGIS 2.0 after using 1.7.4 and 1.8 previous.

It looks great but there are a lot of plugins missing.  I understand from the install that  I may need to install them again for fear of system conflicts.  However some really good plugins are missing. The following are the main ones:

- Numerical Vertex Edit
- Easy custom Labelling
- OpenLayers Plugin
- OpenStreetMap
- QGIS Cloud
- Remove Empty Layers
- Spatial Query

This list is not exhaustive but I am sure they are built in somewhere and can't find them.

Comment: `Open Layers Pluggin` and `Spatial Query` are there.  `Spatial Query` is a C++ plugin that is built into QGIS so it is always shipped.

Comment: Just install a copy of Lisboa (you can download it from the previous versions section on the QGIS site) so you have access to the old plugins while waiting for the developers to update the plugins.  Remember that many plugins are written by 3rd parties and given freely for the benefit of the QGIS community so let's not be too harsh that some are not available in v2 yet.  We should also be thankful that Open Source projects update on average faster than proprietary software!

Comment: @MappaGnosis: Could there be some effort by volunteer developers on updating most wanted plugins that aren't ported yet by their original creators?

Comment: @Andre: I'm sure there could be and we shouldn't assume that all the creators of plugins will migrate them as they may be busy with other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All QGIS plugins have to be rewritten to match the new API used by QGIS 2.0.

Some plugin developers may have lost interest in developing their plugins, or have not read the notification about it.

So you have to wait until someone upgrades the plugins, and stick to QGIS 1.8.0 until your favourite plugins are ported to QGIS 2.0

Comment: Not rewritten. Just updated. Rewritten sounds like you have to change everything, so may need lots some very little. See http://nathanw.net/2013/09/22/broken-qgis-plugins/

Comment: For the end user without programming skills, it is nearly the same...

Comment: Yeah true.  It's more the implied work using the term "rewritten" vs "updated"

Comment: Cheers. I will await someone who can speak python.

Answer (score 0):

Of these a two seem to be installed by default, but if not can be installed through: Plugins>Manage and Install Plugins...  Get More Tab

Available:

Open Layers Plugin

Spatial Query

Comment: Sorry, but most of them are not there is the point of the question. Spatial Query is, my mistake on that. But Open layers is not. and that is a big one.

Comment: Openlayers works for me